# Nokogiri loadError only inside Jenkins job

Tags: ruby, maven, jenkins, nokogiri

I have set up a mvn exec plugin execution, which runs a Ruby script that requires Nokogiri. The Jenkins job is created to build the Java project. This Ruby script is supposed to run in the generate-sources phase of the Maven build.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>                           
      <configuration>                           
        <workingDirectory>src/main/resources</workingDirectory>
        <arguments>                             
          <argument>../../../test.rb</argument>
          <argument>test.txt</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable>/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby</executable>                  
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I installed Nokogiri on the Jenkins box, and when I run the Ruby script outside of Jenkins it works fine, but when the Jenkins build is triggered it fails with:

> `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)     from
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

My Ruby script:

```
require 'nokogiri'

if ARGV.size == 0 
  abort("Please provide the file name as first argument!")
end

ARGV.each { |input_file|     
  output_file = "_#{input_file}" 

  puts "Processing --- #{input_file} ->  #{output_file}"

  f = File.open(input_file)
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

  ##Move style tag to top of the body content  
  style  = doc.at_css "style"
  body = doc.at_css "body"  
  style.parent = body
  first_child = body.first_element_child
  first_child.add_previous_sibling(style)

  File.open(output_file, "w") do |fout|
    fout.puts doc.to_html
  end   
}
```

Jenkins is not able to load Nokogiri, while outside of Jenkins this script works fine.

Comment: Have you tried adding rvm to PATH? Something like `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"`

Comment: ya.. below is in the PATH `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin`

Comment: I see no rmv path here, only for ruby.. Anyway where is nokogiri downloaded and installed?

Comment: I did `gem install nokogiri`
I even tried `rvm gemset use global` and install

Comment: When running jobs under something like Jenkins, it's really important to make sure the environment is set up correctly. Confirm your paths and environment variables are correct for the user running in that job.

Comment: @theTinMan I can successfully run the ruby script even after `su <jenkins-user>`
`echo $PATH` returns 
{/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin}

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by again setting the environment variables in the shell where jenkins runs the job.

```
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.1.5
```

Added the above command as a pre build shell command.